# IS there a way to count the repetition of ID in an SSRS dataset column

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to count the number of times a call ID is repeated in a specific column in SQL SSRS 2016. i need to sort the results by date. i have tried Count(NULLIF(0, callid)) AS count but is not working. i also tried HAVING Count(callid) > 1  but still not working.

Comment: Can you post some example data with expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in SSRS using a `COUNT` function with a nested `IIF`.

```
= SUM(IIF(Fields!callid.Value = "[YourSpecificIDHere]", 1, 0))
```

However, if you mean that you intend to get a count of each ID and have it attached to any row with that ID, you can use the window function in SQL to get your count.

```
COUNT(callid) OVER (PARTITION BY callid ORDER BY date) AS count
```

Comment: Do you mean `SUM` in the first expression? If you use `COUNT`, won't that count 0's as well? Unless you change the `0` to `NOTHING`. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @BJones Good catch, must've answered this before I finished my coffee.  Updated the expression.

Comment: I know what you mean!